# Java RSA Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm having trouble decrypting some text

```
public class mainClass {

    private static Cipher cipher;

    private static KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
    private static KeyPair pair;
    private static PrivateKey privateKey;
    private static PublicKey publicKey;

    public static void createKeys() {
        pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        publicKey = pair.getPublic();
    }

    public static String encryptText(String msg)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    }

    public static String decryptText(String msg)
            throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg)), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int keylength = 1024;

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(keylength, random);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        createKeys();

        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\caleb.baker\\Downloads\\test100k.db");
        byte[] b = new byte[f.available()];
        int offset = 0;
        String asf = "";
        f.read(b);
        String test = new String(b);
        for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x += 117) {
            try {
                asf += encryptText(test.substring(x, x + 117));
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                asf += encryptText(test.substring(x));
            }
        }
        String t = asf;
        asf = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < t.length(); x += 117) {
            System.out.println("run");
            try {
                asf += decryptText(test.substring(x, x + 117));
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                asf += decryptText(test.substring(x));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error i get is
Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits

at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)

at mainClass.decryptText(mainClass.java:60)

at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:162)
```

I'm pretty new to encryption. the symmetric AES worked great, and I know its faster but for my own curiosity I want to time RSA. Another error I will get is a bad padding exception. I have been working on it some but I think that may be laying around in my code somewhere waiting to get me.

Also the Encryption works fine. I did not check to see if it was correct but I did print out the length to make sure the string was long enough. the loop for decryption never makes it past the first loop

Comment: Lots of issues here including confusing characters and bytes, assuming `InputStream.available()` is a reliable way to measure the size of a file, relying on provider defaults. You are also encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public key. The nearest cause of your error is that you are decrypting 117 character blocks but the output of encryption followed by base64 encoding is in 172 character blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple issues with your program

- as already commented - wrong keys are used (private key is to be used to decrypt, public key is to be used to encrypt)
- RSA is to be used  to encrypt only limited amount of data, not text of any length. It can be used that way, but under some circumstances it may be not secure
- `Last unit does not have enough valid bits` means the base64 encoded value is not valid. Decoding base64 means transforming 4 bytes of 6 bit encoding to 3 bytes of 8 bits. so the length of the decoded part must be multiplier of 4 (which 1177 is not)  the same goes with the encryption loop, just joining multiple base64 string doesn't necessary result in valid b64 value.
- I did not get purpose of the loops in the program., imho it is overcomplicated, you ought to keep it simple. what were you trying to achieve?
- `Another error I will get is a bad padding exception.`  RSA (default cipher RSA/ECB/pkcs1padding) adds padding to the value to be encrypted. So you cannot just take any value and decrypt it otherwise the padding won't be valid (which happens in the loops with some substring)

Some time ago I wrote a [blog about encryption in Java](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) you may get some inspiration from